# return type and actual return type

Tags: python, function, types

```
def f(x: int) -> str:
    return 0
```

for the function above, how can I raise `AssertionError` because function is supposed to return a str type, but it returns a int type?

Comment: If you're writing the function, and you know it should return a string, why not make sure it really returns a string (or possibly `None`)? That kind of is your responsibility as a programmer, to make sure there's no errors in the code you create.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm doing this because I'm currently writing a class object which checks annotation of a function, so I need to specify this kind of errors in my class

Comment: How are you supposed to check the annotations? Are you doing static analysis, or run-time analysis? Please [edit] your question to give us as many details about your goal, what you're doing, and what problem you're solving.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to type check your function, you can do that in two ways:

At runtime:

```
def f(x: int) -> str:
    result = "" # Initialize your return value here
    # ... manipulate result variable here
    assert isinstance(result, str) # This will cause AssertionError if result is not a str.
    return result
```

Or, you can use a python type checker, like  [MyPy](https://github.com/python/mypy). If you are used to write type hints in your python code, I think the second approach is the more elegant one.

Answer (score 1):

If you raise an assertion error within the function then the execution will stop and you won't get the actual return. The following code segment prints the Exception and the actual return type.

```
def f(x: int) -> str:
    return x

output = f(0)

# Check if the function returned a result with the correct type.
try:
    assert isinstance(output, str)
except AssertionError as err:
    err.args += (f'Parameter {type(output)}', 'expected str')
    print(repr(err))

print(output)
```

Output:

```
AssertionError("Parameter <class 'int'>", 'expected str')
0
```

Comment: @Alex Take a look at my updated answer, and tell me if it works for you. If not we can make some changes.